# qsort on an array of structs is failing (Segmentation fault 11)

Tags: c, arrays, struct, qsort

I am new to C coming from a purely Tcl scripting background.

I have a simple file like this:

```
ship1 Canada 
ship4 China
ship5 USA 
ship2 UK
ship7 Taiwan
ship6 USA 
ship3 Singapore
ship11 Norway
ship8 Senegal
```

I have a function that reads this file and creates an array of structs and returns that file.

```
// the return type of get_ship_info below is a pointer to struct that contains 
// the ship information and the total number of ships counted so far
typedef struct ShipOrigin {
    char *ship_name;
    int ship_count;
} Ship_origin;

Ship_origin* get_ship_info(FILE*);
int cmp (const void *, const void *); 

Ship_origin* get_ship_info(FILE *fp) {
    char *line = malloc(sizeof(MAXLINE));
    Ship_origin *s_map = malloc(sizeof(*s_map));
    int i = 0;
    while( (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp)) != NULL) {
        int len = strlen(line);
        line[len -1] = '\0';
        //printf("%s\n", line);
        s_map[i].ship_name = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXCHAR);
        strcpy(s_map[i].ship_name, line);
        s_map[i].ship_count = i;
        i++;
    }   
    s_map[0].ship_count = i;
    return s_map;
}
```

In `main` I call it and use qsort like below, and this causes a seg fault.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    Ship_origin *s_origin = NULL;
    s_origin = get_ship_info(fp);

    int len = s_origin->ship_count;
    qsort(s_origin,len, sizeof(s_origin), cmp);
    for(i=0; i< s_origin->ship_count; i++) {
        printf("SHIP DATA:%s\n", s_origin[i].ship_name);
    }   
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

My `cmp` function used in qsort compares the ship_name lines in each of the `struct` element of the `s_origin`:

```
int cmp (const void *a, const void *b) {
    Ship_origin* aa = (Ship_origin *) a;
    Ship_origin* bb = (Ship_origin *) b;
    return strcmp(aa->ship_name, bb->ship_name);
}
```

I am new to C and am liking what I am learning (thanks to loss of employment and coronavirus!). Please help me learn what I am doing wrong.

I am also learning lldb to debug which is very much unlike debugging Tcl. It just shows `stop_reason=EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at `qsort`.

Thanks.

Comment: Use index (member `ship_count`) of the first element to tell the length on function return, and use original index (same member) of the first element for printing number... valid but looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated only 1 element for `s_map` while trying to store multiple data.

You should reallocate the array like this:

```
while( (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp)) != NULL) {
    int len = strlen(line);
    line[len -1] = '\0';
    //printf("%s\n", line);
    s_map = realloc(s_map, sizeof(*s_map) * (i + 1)); // add this
    if (s_map == NULL) exit(1); // add this for safety
    s_map[i].ship_name = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXCHAR);
    strcpy(s_map[i].ship_name, line);
    s_map[i].ship_count = i;
    i++;
}
```

Also the third argument of `qsort` is wrong.
It should be size of elements to be sorted, so it should be not `sizeof(s_origin)` but `sizeof(*s_origin)`.

Also the line `char *line = malloc(sizeof(MAXLINE));` is wrong.
Not shown here, I guess `MAXLINE` is an integer and its size should be at most 8 bytes while the line will be longer, so buffer overrun will happen.
It should be `char *line = malloc(MAXLINE);`.

Comment: thank you. If I use: ```s_map = realloc(s_map, sizeof(*s_map) * (i + 1)); ``` that causes an error: ```a.out(5080,0x112c3bdc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff6d196030: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
a.out(5080,0x112c3bdc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6```